# Cancancan nested resource authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have a working ability defined as below:

routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
```

ability.rb

```
can [:manage], Project, invites: {supplier: {:user_id => user.id}}
can [:new, :create], Task
can [:update, :show, :destroy, :edit], Task, user_id: user.id
```

Tasks Controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :project
load_and_authorize_resource :task, :through => :project
```

This properly lets the user create a task, if they are invited to a project.

However, I don't want the user to be able to :manage the project. I just need the user to be able to index the project as below.

ability.rb

```
can [:index], Project, invites: {supplier: {:user_id => user.id}} ## breaks when changing :manage to :index here
can [:new, :create], Task
can [:update, :show, :destroy, :edit, :index], Task, user_id: user.id
```

When I put in the the abilities above, the user can no longer access or perform any actions on the task. How do I create a task ability through the project, with only giving an :index ability to the project?

Comment: `can [:index], Project, invites: {supplier: { user_id: user.id }}` - but you really are at the point of complexity where Pundit is a much better choice than CanCanCan.

Comment: True. This is the last piece I need for authentication. Seeing if I can avoid a rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably define that a user can `read` a Project when invited. Therefore:

a user can read a project if is invited ( I guess the condition `invites: { supplier: { user: user} }` defines an invited user )

```
can :read, Project, invites: { supplier: { user: user} }
```

then you have to say that a user can create Tasks for projects to which he got invited, then:

```
can [:new, :create], Task, project: { invites: { supplier: { user: user} } }
```

in the end you define that the user can manage his own tasks on projects he his invited to:

```
can :manage, Task, user: user, project: { invites: { supplier: { user: user} } }
```

You can also simplify the conditions by extracting

```
invited_to = { invites: { supplier: { user: user} } }
can :read, Project, invited_to
can [:new, :create], Task, project: invited_to
can :manage, Task, user: user, project: invited_to
```

Comment: Almost there, I need to be able to define custom actions (one singe method) on the project for this role, so, I have to avoid `:read` and `:manage` on `Project` as those assign too many rights.  I could take out the project auth all together, but, as soon as I do `can :manage, Task, user: user` it allows the user to create a Task under any project they weren't invited to with URL hacking..

Comment: `:read` should be ok in your case fir the Project since it gives `:index` and `:show`. About the second point I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up only giving a `show` permission for the project, and restricted the page out by role.